# adding attributes to xelement using namespace

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have developed the following code to generate an `xElement` (C# language):

```
new XElement("Transmission",
     new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns.GetName("xmlns").LocalName, "http://www.irs.gov/efile"),
     new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
     new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation),
            ........
```

The three namespaces are declared like this:

```
    private static XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    private static XNamespace schemaLocation = XNamespace.Get("http://www.irs.gov/efile ./ExtendedCommon/Transmission.xsd");
    private static XNamespace xmlnsLocation = XNamespace.Get("http://www.irs.gov/efile");
```

But when I generate the xml out of this, I get the following error:

```
The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://www.irs.gov/efile' within the same start element tag.
```

Could someone help?

Comment: Consider to post the XML you want to create, then we can help with the code. I think you want `XNamespace df = "http://www.irs.gov/efile"; XElement t = new XElement(df + "Transmission", ...)` to create the element in a certain namespace but I am not sure.

Comment: Also note that `XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");` can be shortened to `XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
XNamespace df = "http://www.irs.gov/efile";
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
string schemaLocation = "ExtendedCommon/Transmission.xsd";

XElement t = new XElement(df + "Transmission",
  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
  new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", string.Format("{0} {1}", df, schemaLocation)));
```

That will generate the XML

```
<Transmission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.irs.gov/efile ExtendedCommon/Transmission.xsd" xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" />
```

Comment: Perfect solution. It saved my day. Appreciate a lot.

Comment: I spoke little before. It is wroking fine except the name space xmlns is being extended to all of its child elemetns also, which I do not want.

Comment: I resolved this issue by adding df in front of every XElement. Like new XElement(df + "ddddd", value). When I did this the issue was resolved.

Comment: Yes, if you want to create further elements in a certain namespace, you have to use that `XNamespace` to construct the `XName` each time you call the `XElement` constructor.